# Java Spring and CORS

Tags: java, spring, cors

I need to create pack of webservices, which will be requestet by javascript from other domains.

I've foud, that there is a cool package for support cross-domain: CORSFilter.

I saw, that the implementation of CORS is by add to web.xml:

```
<web-app>
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But i've got my own configuration:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



</web-app>
```

When i'm trying to add CORS configuration to my web.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>/*</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

I get an error:

```
    mar 19, 2013 2:17:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
mar 19, 2013 2:17:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
```

How i should implement it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the "filter-mapping" section you're having a "servlet-name" tag but what's inside is actually a url pattern and not a servlet name. So you should have either

```
<servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
```

or

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should maybe consider using the native CORS support available as of [Spring Framework 4.2 GA](https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/31/spring-framework-4-2-goes-ga). See [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) for more details.

If you prefer continuing using a `Filter` based approach, for example if you are not using Spring MVC but just Spring Web, a Spring [`CorsFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/CorsFilter.html) is also provided.