# Spring Data Rest and Cors

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cors, spring-data-rest

I am developing a Spring Boot application with a Rest interface and a dart fronted.

The XMLHttpRequest does execute a OPTIONS request which is handled totally correct. After this, the final GET ("/products") request is issued and fails:

*No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63343' is therefore not allowed access.*

After some debugging I have found the following:
The AbstractHandlerMapping.corsConfiguration is populated for all Subclasses except RepositoryRestHandlerMapping. In the RepositoryRestHandlerMapping no corsConfiguration is present / set at creation time and so it won't get recognized as cors path / resource.
=> No CORS headers attached
Could that be the problem? How can I set it?

Configuration classes:

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowCredentials(false).allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("PUT", "POST", "GET", "OPTIONS", "DELETE").exposedHeaders("Authorization", "Content-Type");
    }

   ...
}
```

I even tried to set the Cors per annotation:

```
@CrossOrigin( methods = RequestMethod.GET, allowCredentials = "false")
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, String> {


}
```

Raw request headers:

```
GET /products HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/43.0.2357.130 Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:63343/inventory-web/web/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

Raw response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 30 Jul 2015 15:58:03 GMT
```

Versions used:
Spring Boot 1.3.0.M2
Spring 4.2.0.RC2

What do I miss?

Comment: I don't know Spring Boot, but I've done it using a filter on the Java side and some extra params on the Dart side, see dart:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427203/dart-browserclient-post-not-including-my-cookies
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846309/cors-filter-not-working-as-intended

Also post some network traces, it makes it easier to see what's actually being sent and received.

Comment: The filter should IMHO no longer be necessary: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31539691/1309964 - For the OPTIONS request this works already.

Comment: Sounds like great new annotation to use! Looking at your response headers, I'm expecting to see the following headers which I'm not: `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true/false.`
`Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE`
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://____.com`
`Access-Control-Max-Age:60`
I'm assuming Spring Boot handles annotation scanning automatically or do you set it up manually?

I'm assuming these annotations are sitting in some sort of controller, do you have an @Controller annotation or some annotation that tells spring to scan that class?

Comment: Does it work if you put it directly on top of you `@Controller` / `@RestController` like in this example?
https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

Comment: This commit should solve the issue : [DATAREST-573 - Add support for new CORS configuration mechanisms intr…](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/commit/a3870ca528433ae384a934da4fd29c2a8cd149b8), it will be included in version 2.6

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Indeed, before Spring Data REST 2.6 (Ingalls) only `HandlerMapping` instances created by Spring MVC `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and controllers annotated with `@CrossOrigin` were CORS aware.

But now that [DATAREST-573](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-573) has been fixed, `RepositoryRestConfiguration` now exposes a `getCorsRegistry()` for global setup and `@CrossOrigin` annotations on repositories are also recognized so this is the recommended approach. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42403956/1092077 answer for concrete examples.

For people that have to stick to Spring Data REST 2.5 (Hopper) or previous versions, I think the best solution is to use a filter based approach. You could obviously use Tomcat, Jetty or [this one](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html), but be aware that Spring Framework 4.2 also provides a [`CorsFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/CorsFilter.html) that use the same CORS processing logic that `@CrossOrigin` and `addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry)` approaches. By passing an [`UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/cors/UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.html) instance to the `CorsFilter` constructor parameter, you could easily get something as powerful as Spring native CORS global support.

If you are using Spring Boot (which supports `Filter` beans), it could be something like:

```java
@Configuration
public class RestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK it works. However I can't use it yet because I need more flexibility/convenience with Access-Control-Allow-Origin : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797633/how-to-set-dynamic-access-control-allow-origin-based-on-origin-http-request-head

Comment: I edited your answer so that most people looking to "replicate" the "default" Spring Boot configuration would get a sane AllowCredentials=true config, and not frustrated for hours like I did! :'(

Comment: In order to make this work with Spring-Security, I had to use the first solution and add the `CorsFilter`to the Spring-Security filter chain like this:
`http.addFilterBefore(corsFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class)`

Comment: For some reason, `new CorsFilter(source)` would throw a runtime exception, so I ended up creating a SimpleCorsFilter by hand.  But this answer did let me know I wasn't crazy when everything looked like it was wired correctly.

Comment: @Kiview & adeady a vote to https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-573 would be appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks. I hope that we get the solution to DATAREST-573 soon.

Comment: I have updated my [Spring + CORS blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework#filter-based-cors-support) with the `FilterRegistrationBean`. Please notice that `config.addAllowedMethod("*")` is supported.

Comment: BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'corsFilter' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter' but was actually of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean

Comment: This is the one. +1

Comment: For me this worked after setting `bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);`

Answer (score 27):

Since [the Ingalls train has been realised](https://spring.io/blog/2017/01/30/what-s-new-in-spring-data-release-ingalls), the support of CORS in Spring Data is now on. There are two ways to deal with:

1. The `@CrossOrigin` annotation with specifying `origins`, `methods`, and `allowedHeaders` over a `@RepositoryRestResource` interface.

   ```
   @CrossOrigin(...)
   @RepositoryRestResource
   public interface PageRepository extends CrudRepository<Page, Long> { ... }
   ```
2. A global configuration with the `RepositoryRestConfiguration` inside a `@Configuration` class. Marking repositories by the `@CrossOrigin` is not necessary then.

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class GlobalRepositoryRestConfigurer extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

       @Override
       public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
           config.getCorsRegistry()
                     .addMapping(CORS_BASE_PATTERN)
                     .allowedOrigins(ALLOWED_ORIGINS)
                     .allowedHeaders(ALLOWED_HEADERS)
                     .allowedMethods(ALLOWED_METHODS);
        }

   }
   ```

Comment: Somehow the 1st approach didn't work for me with a JpaRepository, but the 2nd did. Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: @dvdgsng, can I have a look at a piece of code where you tried to use the first option? here is a room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142423

Comment: Thanks ! You save my mental health from a bug from the hell !

Comment: Unfortunately neither of suggested solutions works in Spring Boot 1.4.3 and 1.5.4 - Camden.SR4. The 1st one makes no difference, and the 2nd finds no `getCorsRegistry` method in `RepositoryRestConfiguration`.

Answer (score 9):

For some reason the approach suggested in the accepted answer above didn't work for me after upgrading from Spring Boot 1.5.2 to 1.5.6.

As also pointed out by @BigDong's comment, the exception I got was:

> BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeExcep‌​tion: Bean named 'corsFilter' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter' but was actually of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean

So here's what I came up with to get a "global" CORS configuration for all endpoint in our REST API, whether they're implemented using Spring Data Rest or Spring MVC, with all endpoints protected by Spring Security.

I wasn't able to hook a `CorsFilter` into the request pipeline at the right point, so instead I configured SDR and MVC separately, however using the same configuration for their `CorsRegistry` via this helper:

```
public static void applyFullCorsAllowedPolicy(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**") //
            .allowedOrigins("*") //
            .allowedMethods("OPTIONS", "HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH") //
            .allowedHeaders("*") //
            .exposedHeaders("WWW-Authenticate") //
            .allowCredentials(true)
            .maxAge(TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(1));
}
```

And then for MVC:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class CustomWebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // enables CORS as per
        // https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/cors.html#cors
        http.cors()
            .and() // ...
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                applyFullCorsAllowedPolicy(registry);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And then for SDR:

```
public class CustomRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
    config.setReturnBodyOnCreate(true);
    config.setReturnBodyForPutAndPost(true);
    config.setReturnBodyOnUpdate(true);
    config.setMaxPageSize(250);
    config.setDefaultPageSize(50);
    config.setDefaultMediaType(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON);
    config.useHalAsDefaultJsonMediaType(true);

    CustomWebSecurityConfiguration.applyFullCorsAllowedPolicy(config.getCorsRegistry());
}
```

Here's some further reference on the subject that helped me come up with this answer:

- https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/cors.html

Answer (score 8):

**RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter** is deprecated from 3.1 so if you used spring boot and data-rest version 3.1 above you can directly implement **RepositoryRestConfigurer** :

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigRepositoryRest implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {
@Override
public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
    config.getCorsRegistry()
            .addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
}
```

}

Comment: Can't thank you enough!!! This works with 2.3.4.RELEASE and reactjs (axios). So how does one find a solution like this in spring boot tutorials/documentation? @CrossOrigina annotation doesn't seem to work with data repositories. I spent two days looking for the solution and this is the answer. What was I missing?

Comment: This worked! I was trying a similar approach with a `@Bean public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {` but failed to make it work.

Comment: Just to add to the above, this is the recommended way according to the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#reference  under the chapter "Customizing Spring Data REST" section "Configuring CORS".

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to hitting spring rest service from angular.
Spring rest project deployed in tomcat server and angular is default angular server.
I faced this issue when it is hitting from angular to service.
I tried to follow

https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/

but problem still there.
Thanks to my senior 'Abbas bhai', he suggested please add some configuration in spring configuration file to avoid this problem, so I added this code in spring configuration.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("org.liferayasif.backend")
public class RestConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer){
        configurer.enable();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter#addCorsMappings(org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry)
     * To avoid 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
     * Above error arising when I am hitting from angular to our rest service
     */
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }

}
```

This method resolved my 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' cors.

```
@Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
```

For reference can download my whole project

My github url link:

https://github.com/asifaftab87/SpringPersistenceHibernate

Branch  - security

Project - Model