# How to set dynamic Access-Control-Allow-Origin based on Origin HTTP request header in Spring Framework 4.2/Boot 1.3?

Tags: spring, cordova, spring-boot, cors, spring-data-rest

[Spring 4.2 has CORS support](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework), however allowed Origin(s) must be set manually. Which is problematic when combined with authentication, because authentication not supported with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

How to set this automatically? Very useful for Ionic/Cordova clients.

i.e. if client sends `Origin: assets-library://whatever/` then server will send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: assets-library://whatever/`

Feature request: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18088 (formerly SPR-13511)

Comment: I answered you in the comments of the JIRA issue, this should be already supported.

Answer (score 1):

By "default" of Spring Boot, Spring 4.2 does support my described scenario when using `@CrossOrigin` or `addCorsMappings()`.

What's **not** default, is by using [Sébastien's technique described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31748398/122441) (I've since updated the answer). Care must be taken to:

```
config.setAllowCredentials(true);
```

because the **real** default of `CorsConfiguration` is it's `null` which is treated as `false`.