# Enabling Cross Origin Resource Sharing for Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I'm developing Spring (non-Boot) application with Spring 4.2.1 version. I've enabled CORS for Spring MVC in web configuration file.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"com.hello.web", "com.hello.rest"})
@Import(RestMvcConfig.class)
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}


@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**");
}

}
```

And it was working correct. But now i started to use String Data Rest 2.4 and integrated it with Spring MVC. How to enable Cross Origin Resources Sharing for Spring Data Rest controllers? I've tried to fix it with filter bean [Spring Data Rest and Cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724994/spring-data-rest-and-cors)

```
@Configuration
public class RestMvcConfig extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

@Override
public RepositoryRestConfiguration config() {
    RepositoryRestConfiguration config = super.config();
    config.setBasePath("/api");
    config.setDefaultMediaType(new MediaType("application", "json", Charset.forName("utf-8")));
    return config;
}

@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true); // you USUALLY want this
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
}
```

But CORS is still not allowed.
    No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested       resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

How to enable CORS for Spring Data Rest?

Comment: it should work for the entire app.

Comment: please see [this][1] SO thread. you should register Filter bean. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724994/spring-data-rest-and-cors

Comment: I've seen it and i did register a filter bean, but it didn't wokr. That's why i aksed my own question. As i understand it was solution example for spring-boot projects.

Comment: add your config where you register the filter bean

Comment: I've added config files to this questions.