# Cors not work with spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, cors

I have a problem that I can't access logout, because cors filter runs after spring security filters. I have searched a lot about this and methods described here

[Spring Security Logout doesn't work with Spring 4 CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154711/spring-security-logout-doesnt-work-with-spring-4-cors)

or

[Spring Data Rest and Cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724994/spring-data-rest-and-cors/31748398#31748398)

don't work.

My configuration

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfiguration {

@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true); // you USUALLY want this
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

}

and my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> logout(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    // ...
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

in browser I can see this :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/logout. The request was redirected to 'http://localhost:8080/login?logout', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

Is there any solution to this bug ?

Comment: did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724994/spring-data-rest-and-cors/31748398#comment57207680_31748398 ?

Comment: I solved using http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin().disable(); in configure method

Comment: @RC. do you mean this http.addFilterBefore(corsFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class) ? If so, it doesn't work