# Unauthorized Error when using jHipster oAuth despite CORS

Tags: spring, authentication, oauth, cors, jhipster

I am running a jHipster instance with oAuth authentication and CORS enabled on the server. I've added the following bean:

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"}));
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", config);
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/v2/api-docs", config);
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/oauth/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

and added .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/token").permitAll() to ResourceServerConfiguration configuration.

When I attempt to authenticate a user (using jHipster running on a server) from an app running locally on a browser, I get:
Request Method:OPTIONS - Status Code:401 Unauthorized

It seems CORS is not configured properly to handle pre-flight authentication POST requests.

I've tried to implement some solutions proposed at [Spring Data Rest and Cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724994/spring-data-rest-and-cors/31748398#31748398) and [Spring Data Rest and Cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724994/spring-data-rest-and-cors/31748398#31748398) to no avail.

Is this something specific that can be done in jHipster to enabled authentication to work from a browser or app (not running on the jhipster server)?

Comment: What version of JHipster are you using? If it's a recent version, you can enable CORS by simply uncommenting the "cors" section in application.yml.

Comment: @MattRaible Hi Matt, thanks for looking into this (BTW I'm a big fan of your work and the volkswagen of course). In any case, I am using jHipster 2.23.0. CORS is already enabled but there some issue with the preflight authentication POST as described above. My own services work fine with CORS.

Comment: I'm a big fan of my VW too! I can't wait until it's finished. ;) Have you tried adding these extra lines to the CsrfCookieGeneratorFilter? http://jhipster.github.io/tips/006_tips_enable_cross_origin_requests.html

Comment: @jvence hi, any luck with this? I am running into the same issue..

Comment: @i_raqz Sorry no luck. Just waiting for jHipster 3.0 to come out and will see if it still exists

Comment: @jvence I just raised an issue on jhipster's repo.

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/3237

Hopefully it gets fixed soon. I need to go prod using this :(
Is there any alternate or a workaround?

Comment: @i_raqz Did you end up solving this issue? Having a similar issue with jHipster 3.0 (using the executable generated war file)

Answer (score 5):

I uncommented lines of CORS

```
cors: #By default CORS are not enabled. Uncomment to enable.
    allowed-origins: "*"
    allowed-methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
    allowed-headers: "*"
    exposed-headers:
    allow-credentials: true
    max-age: 1800
```

Added in SecurityConfiguration

```
            **.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")**
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .antMatchers("/scripts/**/*.{js,html}")
            .antMatchers("/bower_components/**")
            .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
            .antMatchers("/assets/**")
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
            .antMatchers("/api/register")
            .antMatchers("/api/activate")
            .antMatchers("/api/login/**")
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset_password/init")
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset_password/finish")
            .antMatchers("/test/**");
    }
```

And it has been working so far.