# Enable CORS On Spring accessing MongoDB data

Tags: spring, cors

I'm trying to develop a RestFul Web Service with Spring, that fetches data from a mongoDB collection and serves it to a client. To build the service i followed [this guide on spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/). Everything went well, i can access data from mongoDB and search it for the data structure name.
The troubles began when i tried to manage requests from my client, i receive classical error of same-domain-policy violation.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

The project is EXTREMELY simple, is composed of those 3 classes:

**Frames.java**

```
@Id
private String Id;

private String frameName;
private ArrayList<String> frameElements;

public String getId() {
    return Id;
}

public String getFrameName() {
    return frameName;
}

public ArrayList<String> getFrameElements() {
    return frameElements;
}
```

**FrameRestFulServiceApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FrameRestFulServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FrameRestFulServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**FramesRepository.java**

```
 @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "frames", path = "frames")
    public interface FramesRepository extends MongoRepository<Frames, String>{

    List<Frames> findByFrameNameLike(@Param("frameName") String frameName);
    List<Frames> findByFrameName(@Param("frameName") String frameName);

}
```

I tried different methods found in the documentation [See here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html) but without results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question is [Spring Data Rest and Cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724994/spring-data-rest-and-cors)

The answer is that if you are using Spring Boot (which supports `Filter` beans), it could be something like:

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true); // you USUALLY want this
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add a class like this?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

it worked for me

Comment: I just tried but it doesn't work, keeps giving me the same error