# keycloak CORS filter spring boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, cors, keycloak

I am using keycloak to secure my rest service. I am refering to the tutorial given [here](http://slackspace.de/articles/authentication-with-spring-boot-angularjs-and-keycloak/). I created the rest and front end. Now when I add keycloak on the backend I get CORS error when my front end makes api call.

Application.java file in spring boot looks like

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfiguration() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/api/*")
                        .allowedMethods(HttpMethod.GET.toString(), HttpMethod.POST.toString(),
                                HttpMethod.PUT.toString(), HttpMethod.DELETE.toString(), HttpMethod.OPTIONS.toString())
                        .allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The keycloak properties in the application.properties file look like

```
keycloak.realm = demo
keycloak.auth-server-url = http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.ssl-required = external
keycloak.resource = tutorial-backend
keycloak.bearer-only = true
keycloak.credentials.secret = 123123-1231231-123123-1231
keycloak.cors = true
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].name = spring secured api
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].authRoles[0] = admin
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].authRoles[1] = user
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] = /api/*
```

The sample REST API  that I am calling

```
@RestController
public class SampleController {    
    @RequestMapping(value ="/api/getSample",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public string home() {
        return new string("demo");
    }        
}
```

the front end keycloak.json properties include

```
{
  "realm": "demo",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "tutorial-frontend",
  "public-client": true
}
```

The CORS error that I get

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8090/api/getSample. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

Comment: You may prefer asking a concrete question. Otherwise you might get answers that are no valid solution for you.

Comment: Can you provide the whole stacktrace?

Comment: There are no error on the server side. Hence no stack trace. The error i on the client side when my angularJS app makes the rest call I get the CORS error on browser console

Comment: do you get the error message on Chrome only?

Comment: your html/js files are served from port 9000, you try to load them from port 8090 and your json config is using port 8080; normally you must use the same port 8080

Comment: Did you fix this problem ? I am having same issue

Comment: Did you fix the problem? I am also having the same issue.

Answer (score 8):

I know.. the Problem is quite Old.
But if you've Problems with the local development with Spring Boot + Keycloak you can use the Config

```
keycloak.cors=true
```

in your application.properties.

Cheers :)

Comment: Worked for me! If you don't really care about CORS (for example building an app to learn something like me) that's the way to go. I've also disabled CORS using `RepositoryRestConfigurer` like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60014831/9134945

Answer (score 3):

Try creating your CORS bean like my example. I recently went through the same thing (getting CORS to work) and it was a nightmare because the SpringBoot CORS support is currently not as robust or straightforward as the MVC CORS.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(0);
    return bean;
}
```

This is how I set it up to accept any origin application-wide, but if you change a few of the parameters you should be able to replicate what you want. ie. if you wanted to add only the methods you mentioned, chain some `addAllowedMethod()`. Allowed origins would be the same, and then your `addMapping("/api/*")` would become `source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/*", config);`.

Edit:

[Spring Data Rest and Cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724994/spring-data-rest-and-cors)

Take a look at this. Sebastian is on the Spring engineering team so this is about as good as you're going to get for an official answer.

Comment: sure i will let you know when i try it once I back from the holidays next week

Comment: changing my bean to what you have posted did not work. I think ill try using spring mvc and not use spring boot at all

Answer (score 3):

I came here with the same problem and fix it ommiting authentication for OPTIONS method only, like this:

```
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].security-collections[0].omitted-methods[0]=OPTIONS
```

It worked for me because the OPTIONS request Keycloack does, does not include Authentication header.

**UPDATE**
There was something with my browser's cache so I could not see the real impact of a change in my backend code. It looks like what really worked for me was enabling all CORS origins at @RestController level, like this:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
public class UsersApi {...}
```

Comment: I need to get a beer for you

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to code examples, but based on the code configurations you have included, it looks like a missing configuration is causing spring to exclude CORS headers.

J. West's response is similar to recent issues I encountered with Spring and CORS, I would however caution you to look into which implementation a spring example references, because there are two.  [Spring Security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/cors.html) and [Spring MVC Annotations](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework).  Both of these implementations work independent of each other, and can not be combined.

When using the filter based approach as you are (even boiled down), the key was to set allow credentials to true, in order for the authentication headers to be sent by the browser across domains.  I would also advise using the full code method proposed above, as this will allow you to create a far more configurable web application for deployment across multiple domains or environments by property injection or a service registry.

Comment: Good point on the annotations. I edited my answer to include a link to a similar question that a Spring engineer was active on. If you had the same issue I'm guessing you came across it at some point.

Answer (score 2):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is supposed to be set by the server application basis the `Origin` request header provided in the request to the server application. Usually browsers set the `Origin` header in request whenever they sense a cross origin request being made. And they expect a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in response to allow it.

Now, for keycloak, I struggled with the same issue. Looking at [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-1886), it seems like keycloak does not add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in case of error response. However, for me it was not adding this header in the response even in case of success response.

Looking into the code and adding breakpoints, I noticed that the webOrigin for client object was not getting populated from the `Origin` header even if passed and hence CORS was not adding the access control response header.

I was able to get it working by adding the following line of code just before the CORS build call:

```
client.addWebOrigin(headers.getRequestHeader("Origin").get(0));
```

before:

```
Cors.add(request, Response.ok(res, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)).auth().allowedOrigins(client).allowedMethods("POST").exposedHeaders(Cors.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS).build();
```

Once I built the code with this change and started the server, I started getting the three access control response headers:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Methods 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9000 
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

I am using client credentials grant type; hence i added it only in the `buildClientCredentialsGrant` at [TokenEndpoint.java#L473](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/endpoints/TokenEndpoint.java#L473).

I still need to do some more code diving in order to say for sure that it is a bug for success responses at well and to find a better place to set this on the client object in keycloak code (like where client object is being constructed)

You are welcome to give it a try.

**UPDATE:**
I take this back. I re-registered my client in keycloak with Root URL as http://localhost:9000 (which is my front-end's application port) and i started getting the proper access control response headers. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

I know the problem is too old but, I found better solution.
[Read more at official documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/)

Inside your application.yml file

```
keycloak:
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8180/auth
  realm: CollageERP
  resource: collage-erp-web
  public-client: true
  use-resource-role-mappings: true
  cors: true
  cors-max-age: 0
  principal-attribute: preferred_username
  cors-allowed-methods: POST, PUT, DELETE, GET
  cors-allowed-headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
```

or you can config using application.properties file

```
  keycloak.auth-server-url= http://localhost:8180/auth
  keycloak.realm= CollageERP
  keycloak.resource= collage-erp-web
  keycloak.public-client= true
  keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings= true
  keycloak.cors= true
  keycloak.cors-max-age= 0
  keycloak.principal-attribute= preferred_username
  keycloak.cors-allowed-methods= POST, PUT, DELETE, GET
  keycloak.cors-allowed-headers= X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
```

and my java adaper class

```java
import org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakConfigResolver;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakConfiguration;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;

import javax.ws.rs.HttpMethod;

@KeycloakConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
public class KeycloakSecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.cors().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**")
                .authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to share with you the solution that worked for me hoping to help whoever is facing the same issue. I am going to give you two solutions actually.

**Spring reactive:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

        CorsConfiguration cors_config = new CorsConfiguration();
        cors_config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        cors_config.applyPermitDefaultValues();
        cors_config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000", "null"));
        cors_config.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET","POST","OPTIONS","DELETE"));
        cors_config.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));

        http.cors().configurationSource(source -> cors_config)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges.anyExchange().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login()//Setting Oauth2Login
                .authenticationSuccessHandler(new RedirectServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler("")).and()
                .logout(logout -> logout //Setting Oauth2Logout
                        .logoutHandler(logoutHandler())
                        .logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler()));
        return http.build();
    }

    private ServerLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler() {
        OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler =
                new OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler(this.clientRegistrationRepository);
        // Sets the location that the End-User's User Agent will be redirected to
        // after the logout has been performed at the Provider
        oidcLogoutSuccessHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("");
        return oidcLogoutSuccessHandler;
    }

    private DelegatingServerLogoutHandler logoutHandler() {
        //Invalidate session on logout
        return new DelegatingServerLogoutHandler(
                new SecurityContextServerLogoutHandler(), new WebSessionServerLogoutHandler());
    }


}
```

**Spring MVC:**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        CorsConfiguration cors_config = new CorsConfiguration();
        cors_config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        cors_config.applyPermitDefaultValues();
        cors_config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000", "null"));
        cors_config.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET","POST","OPTIONS","DELETE"));
        cors_config.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        http.cors().configurationSource(source -> cors_config).and()...
        

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

Be sure to have cors enabled on Keycloak too, navigate to
`realm->clients->settings->weborigins`
and submit your permitted origins.

If you are sending credentials or cookies in your requests, be sure to configure it, for example, if you are using ReactJS:

```
const httpConfig = { withCredentials: true };

axios.get('YourUrl', httpConfig)
        .then(response => {})
        .catch(error => {})
        .finally(() => {});
```

Comment: If that can be of any help, I wrote thin wrappers around `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` which enable to set most configuration from application properties, CORS included. Works with Keycloak or any other OIDC authorization-server with the exact same Java conf. Many samples there: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples

Answer (score 0):

When your client is sending an Authentication header, you cannot use 
allowedOrigins("*"). You must configure a specific origin URL.

Comment: That does not work. I changed the allowedOrigins to the URL from from where my client is running. In my project it is running on localhost:9000. Even after changing that i still get the error

Answer (score 0):

Since you have set the property `keycloak.cors = true` in your application.properties file, you have to mention the CORS enabled origins in the Keycloak server. To do that follow the below steps.

Go to `Clients -> Select the client (Token owner) -> Settings -> Web Origins`
Add origins one by one or add * to allow all.
After doing this you have to get a new token. (If you decode the token you will see your origins as `allowed-origins": ["*"]`)

Setting the property `keycloak.cors = false` is another option. But this completely disables CORS.