# Expressing security constraints in Java rather than in properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

Trying to skip the use of the security constraint in the application.properties file:

```
# keycloak.securityConstraints[1].authRoles[0] = admin
# keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] = /admin
```

and expressing them in Java in the Spring Security configuration:

```
super.configure(http);
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin*").hasRole("admin").anyRequest().permitAll();
```

But they are then ignored.

My `application.properties` file:

```
server.compression.enabled = true
server.compression.min-response-size = 2048
server.compression.mime-types = application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain
server.connection-timeout = 5000
server.port = 8082

keycloak.enabled = true
keycloak.auth-server-url = http://localhost:8180/auth
keycloak.ssl-required = external
keycloak.realm = learnintouch
keycloak.resource = learnintouch-web
keycloak.public-client = true
# keycloak.bearer-only = true
# keycloak.credentials.secret = c123028f-2654-403b-a9d0-????????
# keycloak.cors = true
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137766/keycloak-cors-filter-spring-boot

# This is an extra property that allows retrieving the username of the currently
# logged user from the Principal object
keycloak.principal-attribute = preferred_username

# keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0] = user
# keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[1] = admin
# keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] = /user

# keycloak.securityConstraints[1].authRoles[0] = admin
# keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] = /admin

# keycloak.securityConstraints[2].authRoles[0] = user
# keycloak.securityConstraints[2].authRoles[1] = admin
# keycloak.securityConstraints[2].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] = /products
```

My Spring Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

// Avoid prefixing the roles with ROLE_
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
    keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
    auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
}

// Use the Spring Boot properties file instead of the default Keycloak Spring Security Adapter keycloak.json file
@Bean
public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
    return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
}

@Bean
@Override
protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
    return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
}
```

I'm on Spring Boot `2.0.3.RELEASE` and Keycloak adapter `4.0.0.Final`

UPDATE: Following the answer provided bellow, I configured the Keycloak security with the only dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
  <artifactId>keycloak-spring-security-adapter</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/keycloak.json` file contains:

```
{
    "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8180/auth",
    "ssl-required": "external",
    "realm": "learnintouch",
    "resource": "learnintouch-web",
    "public-client": "false",
    "credentials": {
        "secret": "??????..."
    },
    "principal-attribute": "preferred_username"
}
```

The routes are secured by some Spring Security statements:

```
super.configure(http);
http.csrf().disable();
http.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/user*").hasRole("user")
.antMatchers("/admin*").hasRole("admin")
.antMatchers("/products*").hasRole("user")
.anyRequest().permitAll();
```

Comment: Hi Stephane, does your SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with `@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)`?

Comment: Yes it does, I added the missing bit of my class and its annotation.

Comment: Which Keycloak adapter do you use? Spring Boot or Spring Security? I guess that java config is only achievable with the Spring Security one.

Comment: @XtremeBiker I'm using the `keycloak-spring-boot-2-starter` one. I'm also using the `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a more flexible configuration, you'd better go with the [Spring Security adapter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_spring_security_adapter). It provides the ability to specify your configuration in Java, rather than just application properties. The Spring Boot adapter is meant to serve as a basic configuration tool in order to restrict URIs to specific roles.

In order to work with the Spring Security adapter, I'd first remove the Spring Boot adapter, as they can cause conflict. If you still want to use application properties for your configuration to be flexible, you can always use the Spring Boot standard ways, as, in the end, you're just using a `@Configuration` class in a Spring Boot project.

Comment: You say the Spring Boot adapter is meant to restrict URIs to specific roles ? I reckon it is what I'm trying to do with this role / url mappings.

Comment: If using `spring-security-oauth2-client` and `spring-security-oauth2-jose` instead, you'd also advise to use the `keycloak-spring-security-adapter` one ?

Comment: Yes, they are supposed to be used with Keycloak as well, following the article at `https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security`