# Keycloak and Spring Oauth2 - CORS issue

Tags: reactjs, spring, keycloak

I try to connect my Keycloak auth server (SpringBoot) at `localhost:8082` with my React frontend at `localhost:3000` and my login request works fine only when I type it diectly to browser, it doesn't redirect me to login page from my frontend, because I get

> CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing

How does one enable CORS in SpringBoot keycloak?
I've put

```
"redirectUris" : [ "http://localhost:8082/new-client/login/oauth2/code/custom",
      "http://localhost:3000",
      "http://localhost:3000/success"],
"webOrigins" : [ "+" ],
```

in my `realm.json`, but it doesn't solve the issue. I know there is this `"enable-cors" : true` property, but how to use it if my keycloak config resides in `application.properties`? Or do I have to switch to json config? Thanks in advance.

**RESOLVED** by this post [keycloak CORS filter spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137766/keycloak-cors-filter-spring-boot)