# How does a CORS filters protect me from XSS attacks

Tags: java, security, xss

I have the following implementation of a CORS filter:

```
@Singleton
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext,     ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        final int ACCESS_CONTROL_MAX_AGE_IN_SECONDS = 12 * 60 * 60;
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = responseContext.getHeaders();

        headers.add(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, "*");
        headers.add(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        headers.add(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS, "true");
        headers.add(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS, "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        headers.add(ACCESS_CONTROL_MAX_AGE, ACCESS_CONTROL_MAX_AGE_IN_SECONDS);

   }
}
```

Source:

https://gist.github.com/yunspace/36b0546245c5348a34ed

However, I still don't understand how this should prevent XSS and how the browser deal with the added headers. How does this code protect me from XSS attacks?

Comment: It doesn't, since you told your server to accept requests from any origin. Remove that filter, and only scripts coming from your domain will be able to send requests to your server. CORS protects you by default. Adding this filter removes the protection, by allowing scripts of any origin to send you requests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Data Rest and Cors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724994/spring-data-rest-and-cors)

Answer (score 0):

CORS does not protect you from XSS.

The Same Origin Policy (SOP) prevents one domain from getting client-side data from another domain.

CORS allows other domains to be whitelisted so they can get client-side data.

XSS is an attack which accomplishes the same.

Without CORS being enabled, your website is more secure because the SOP is in default "secure" mode. Enabling CORS will slacken the security of the SOP rules.

XSS doesn't care if CORS is enabled or not, if you have an XSS vulnerability you should mitigate it by correct encoding and by implementing a Content Security Policy (CSP).