# Is it possible to create a Cordova app with Spring Boot back end?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api, cordova, cross-domain

Is it possible? I want to create a simple CRUD app using cordova/phonegap and spring boot as backend. Whenever I test the the cordova app in the browser it always say CORS issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely possible, in Cordova/PhoneGap you can use js and it's all you need for sending and receiving the requests if you want to use spring boot as API Backend. 
Check this [link](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/using-existing-backend-services-in-phonegap-cordova-applications).
CORS issue usually happens because of the app and the servers are not host in the same place but you can check for the plugin in Cordova or existed solution but you can use Cordova along with Spring Boot.

Comment: Thank you very much sir @Pooya. Now I got a clear understanding about the issue and was able to make it run. This thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652336/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-spring-data-rest also helped me